# Trigger to export priorities using Zapier

Tags: zapier, conceptual

I am new to Zapier and I have a conceptional question about it.

I am building a prioritization tool and want to export the list of priorities to other project management tools and todo lists, like trello, asana, monday, etc., using Zapier.

When I create a **trigger**, should its form be done:

- for a **single task** including its sorting order, or
- for a **project** with the whole prioritized **list of tasks** using **Line Item Groups**?

My goal is to export tasks as separate trello cards, tasks on asana, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to Zapier support and the answer was, that normally, you export items from one app to another **one-by-one**, although it is also possible to use **Line Item Groups** and **loops** at Zapier with a paid tier.

There is one gotcha, that items are transferred from one app to another in **parallel**, so the sorting order can be guaranteed. But one thing that can ensure their order in most cases is providing the items incrementally **at regular 1-minute intervals**. Also, I include the priority index in the title for clarification, e.g.: "1. Fix the bugs".

You can find more technical details of the implementation at [my blog post](https://dev.to/djangotricks/how-i-integrated-zapier-into-my-django-project-2md7).